# R count number of times a value appears in each row

Tags: r, mode

I need to find out for each mode (mode for a row, not a column) value obtainned, how many times it appear in its row from my data.

This is my data

```
> head(TiposMotivA)
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q16 Q17 Q18 Q19 Q20 Q21
1  5  4  4  4  6  6  7  6  4   6   6   6   4   4   4   4   6   7   4   4   6
2  5  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5   5   7   5   4   3   1   6   6   5   6   7   7
3  4  5  4  4  5  4  5  4  5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5   4   5
4  5  5  7  7  4  6  6  6  7   7   6   7   7   6   6   7   4   7   6   6   7
5  6  1  7  6  7  7  7  7  7   7   6   7   2   2   3   6   3   7   7   7   7
6  4  4  3  3  4  5  4  3  4   7   6   6   4   4   6   4   5   7   6   6   7
```

Dput from this dataset

```
dput(head(TiposMotivA))
    structure(list(Q1 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L), Q2 = c(4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, 4L), Q3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 3L), Q4 = c(4L, 5L, 
    4L, 7L, 6L, 3L), Q5 = c(6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L), Q6 = c(6L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 7L, 5L), Q7 = c(7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L), Q8 = c(6L, 5L, 
    4L, 6L, 7L, 3L), Q9 = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L), Q10 = c(6L, 
    5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Q11 = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Q12 = c(6L, 
    5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L), Q13 = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 4L), Q14 = c(4L, 
    3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L), Q15 = c(4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L), Q16 = c(4L, 
    6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 4L), Q17 = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L), Q18 = c(7L, 
    5L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L), Q19 = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q20 = c(4L, 
    7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L), Q21 = c(6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("Q1", 
    "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9", "Q10", "Q11", 
    "Q12", "Q13", "Q14", "Q15", "Q16", "Q17", "Q18", "Q19", "Q20", 
    "Q21"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Those are the modes for each ROW

```
    [1] "4" "5" "4"   "7"   "7"   "4"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7" 
    [14] "5" "7" "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"
    [27] "7" "7" "7"   "5"   "2"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "6"   "7"
    [40] "4" "3"   "4"   "7"   "5" "6"   "7"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"
    [53] "7"   "6"   "7"   "7"   "5" "7"   "7"   "7"   "7"   "7" 


>
```

Dput for this one

> dput(ModaLinhaA)
>       c("4", "5", "4", "7", "7", "4", "7", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
>       "7", "5", "7", "6", "7", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
>       "7", "7", "7", "7", "5", "2", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "6", "6", 
>       "7", "4", "3", "4", "7", "5", "6", "7", "7", "6", "7", "6", "7", 
>       "7", "7", "6", "7", "7", "5", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7")

Now I need to count how many times each mode appears in each row.
The response should be something like this:

```
Row    Mode    Qt
  1       4    10
  2       5    10
  3       4    11
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming that TiposMotivA and ModaLinhaA have the same length (which I guess is the case in your full dataset):

```
data.frame(Row = 1:nrow(TiposMotivA),
           Mode = ModaLinhaA,
           Qt = rowSums(TiposMotivA == rep(ModaLinhaA,ncol(TiposMotivA))))
```

Comment: @RockScience I think you could simplify it to `TiposMotivA==ModaLinhaA[row(TiposMotivA)]` or `TiposMotivA==rep(ModaLinhaA,ncol(TiposMotivA))`

Comment: @akrun indeed, I have adjusted the answer for your suggestion (although it makes it a bit more confusing for someone who doesn't know how matrix are built in R)

Comment: @RockScience Yes, I concur with you.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a simple function to count the most common number in a vector and then apply it to each row with `apply()`.

Note: I used @Ken_William 's [awesome function for determining the mode of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode) in the below code.

```
Mode <- function(x) { # @Ken_Williams's formula for mode
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

TiposMotivA$Qt <- apply(TiposMotivA, 1, function(x) sum(x == Mode(x)))
```

`sum(x == Mode(x))` is taking the sum of the logical vector returned by `x == Mode(x)`. `TRUE` values count as 1 and `FALSE` values count as zero so the sum of the vector will be the count the modal entry.